# Suggestion for component other than RichTextBox or solution in C#

Tags: c#, checkbox, richtextbox

I'm Currently trying to make a log viewer for analyzing logs. I'm reading the log file that has timestamp, logtype, and text on each line. From this I create an object that has the DateTime object, Type and Text.

The Type is divided in 6 types:

```
public enum LogType
{
    DEBUG = 0,
    EVENT,
    ERROR,
    TEST_STEP,
    WARNING,
    SUCCESS
}
```

The idea is that each log level has a checkbox next to it so that I can quickly add or remove a specified log level. Now this works fine for the small log files with a good spread of different log levels. But when I have huge log files it takes some time to load and as I iterate the array of objects each time a checkbox changes and print again line for line this is quite ineffective.

Is there some better way to connect these objects to each line, or have another component where this is better suited so that you can easily hide or show the log levels?

Best Regards
Andreas

Comment: Does the log file change while you view it, i.e. do you need to check for additional data in real time?

Comment: Nope, it's a "closed" log file. I just need to have a "filter" that is quicker than rewriting the whole text each time I click a checkbox.

Comment: UI Virtualization would definitely help. Not sure if data virtualization will help further: [Data virtualization](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/498#.URyi2WeEP5M). BTW, why a RichTextBox?

Comment: first idea that came to mind for writing the file again although filtered. As I said if there is another type that is easier maintained for my purpose I would gladly use it, although I do not know of the component now.

Answer (score 0):

All i can recommend is using WPF and `UI virtualization` so that you don't burden the UI with a ton of elements that represent a line in the log, and for the filtering use `parlallelization` to speed things up and to leave the UI responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need to update in real time, you could read the entire file, and store the different types in different classes, which inherit from the same base class. For example, you have a base class `Log` and a derived class `DebugLog : Log`, etc.,for each type. You can define and implement most fields in the base class only, since it's simply storing some data, without the need to modify it.

These derived classes store the data separately per type of log level. That way, you can refresh your UI by clearing the list and loading only the data from the classes that you need, without the need to re-iterate through all of the data again (depending on the filters of course).

You would have to build some kind of sort handler to display the data correctly though.